# ¿Cómo agregar atributos a varios `ComboBox` con la misma clase que los agrega?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, combobox

Me encuentro realizando el llenado de varios `ComboBox`, y realicé una clase que les "Agrega" los `Atributos`: `Text` y `Value`, para que su funcionalidad sea igual a la de un combo en `HTML`, que su propiedad `value` es la que se toma y la `Text` es la que se muestra. Ejemplo:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Text</option>
  <option value="2">Text2</option>
</select>
```

En sí el valor que se enviará es lo que hay en el `Value`, el `Text` es solo de muestra. Y ya logré dicha funcionalidad para los `combos` de `WindowsForms`, intenté usar la misma clase que le agregaba esos `atributos` para todos mis `combos`, pero no funciona, y no se me hace tan práctico crear una `clase` para cada `combo`.

Esta es la clase:

```
public class AtributosCombo
{
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public object Value { get; set; } //Atributo que usaré como "Value"

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return Text;//Retorna el Text, con el que se llenará el text de los combos
  }
}
```

En el `Form_Load`, ejecuto este código para hacer el llenado a mi `combo`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  //se crea la instancia cada iteración, de otra manera no se llena
  AtributosCombo item = new AtributosCombo();

  item.Text = "Texto: "+i;//Aquí le asignó un valor al Text
  item.Value = "Value: "+i;// Y aquí al Value

  ComboBox1.Items.Add(item);//Finalmente los agrega al Combo
}
```

Y para verificar que funcionara, hice el evento `comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` para verificar que me arroje el `Value` del `Item` seleccionado.

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //De esta manera seleccionas el "Value" de la opción que se haya seleccionado
  MessageBox.Show((comboBox1.SelectedItem as AtributosCombo).Value.ToString());
}
```

Funciona correctamente, pero quiero saber cómo utilizar la misma `clase` para todos los `combos` a los que les quiera aplicar dicha funcionalidad sin crear una para cada uno.

Comment: Como bien te ha respondido @ElGerar, los combobox tienen ya las propiedades `DisplayMember` y `ValueMember` que hacen exactamente lo que necesitas sin tener que añadir propiedades nuevas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**OPCIÓN 1**

Puedes ahorrarte la creación de la clase y hacer algo como esto:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Text";
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "Value";



        var items = new List<Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
           items.Add(new { Text = "Texto: " + i, Value = "Value: " + i });
        }

        comboBox1.DataSource = items;
        comboBox2.DataSource = new List<Object>(items);
    }

    private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
```

Eso si como ves debes clonar la estructura de datos para que el objeto que se asocie al DataSource sea distinto. (Que viene a ser el problema que tenias antes con tu clase)

**OPCIÓN 2**
Otra opción que tu clase implemente la interfaz `ICloneable`:

```
public class AtributosCombo:ICloneable
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; } //Atributo que usaré como "Value"

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;//Retorna el Text, con el que se llenará el text de los combos
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        var a = new AtributosCombo();
        a.Text = this.Text;
        a.Value = this.Value;
        return a;
    }
}
```

Y la carga de tu formulario quedaría:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            //se crea la instancia cada iteración, de otra manera no se llena
            AtributosCombo item = new AtributosCombo();

            item.Text = "Texto: " + i;//Aquí le asignó un valor al Text
            item.Value = "Value: " + i;// Y aquí al Value

            comboBox1.Items.Add(item);//Finalmente los agrega al Combo
            comboBox2.Items.Add(item.Clone());
        }
    }

    private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //De esta manera seleccionas el "Value" de la opción que se haya seleccionado
        MessageBox.Show((comboBox1.SelectedItem as AtributosCombo).Value.ToString());
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((comboBox2.SelectedItem as AtributosCombo).Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, la solución de la primer opción está perfecto, cómo hago para llenar `var items = new[]{ }` dinámicamente y finalmente mandarlo al `DataSource` del combo, lo estuve intentando, pero no me sale.Si me puedes ayudar te lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Edito la opción 1 para responderte